# How to change the hibernate and suspend settings at a system-wide level in Xfce?

Tags: xfce

I've found the following commands :

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -np '/shutdown/ShowSuspend' -t 'bool' -s 'false'
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -np '/shutdown/ShowHibernate' -t 'bool' -s 'false'
```

To disable suspend and hibernate button from Xfce.

However those commands only effect the user that runs them.

How can I set those parameters system wide ? (all users : new and existing)

I've found that the purpose of `/etc/skel` is for all new users but I can't find information on how to use it with Xfce settings ... and it impacts only new users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often for multi-user systems or for special purposes, Xfce kiosk mode is used so that you can disable all shutdown options for users such as hibernate and suspend. I am running Xubuntu 12.04, but with the ppas for Xfce 4.10 and 4.12. I think there were some issues with kiosk mode a while ago, but it seems to work again now, at least in my tests (see the before and after screenshots below).

Kiosk mode does not need any additional downloads or installations, but will only take effect if you have `/etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk/kioskrc`, so first run

```
sudo mkdir /etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk
sudo touch /etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk/kioskrc
```

There can be several sections of the `kioskrc` file, but we will concentrate on `xfce4-session`, as those are the settings you require. The [official documentation](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/advanced#kiosk_mode) is useful in explaining the options available for `xfce4-session`, but below is an example of the possible content of the `xfce4-session` part of `/etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk/kioskrc`. This would give you a really strict kiosk mode that would leave non-administrative users without any ability to shutdown the machine (or use suspend/hibernate) using the menus or via commands in terminal, although they could still logout. You may **not** want to use these settings, this is just an example (see below for further explanation):

```
[xfce4-session]
CustomizeSplash=NONE
CustomizeChooser=NONE
CustomizeLogout=NONE
CustomizeCompatibility=NONE
Shutdown=NONE
CustomizeSecurity=NONE
```

In place of `Shutdown=NONE` and other settings, you could very reasonably specify your own main user (e.g. `Shutdown=mike`), so **only** you still have the ability to suspend/shutdown using the menu (without resorting to using sudo with command-line shutdown equivalents), but it depends on your purposes. If you want to specify groups use `%groupname`, and for users just specify `username`; the settings `ALL` and `NONE` are self explanatory.

Open the `kioskrc` with your text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk/kioskrc
```

Then copy the above block of settings for `xfce4-session`, **making sure** that you alter the values to suit your purposes. Then save the file, logout and login again with your user or another user to test the settings.

My example of 'before and after' with the strictest kiosk mode settings, which will apply to all users:

a) **Before** with normal Xfce settings, running as user mike:

[image]

b) **After**, with kiosk mode and strict settings enabled, running as user mike:

[image]

For more information, please see [the Xfce documentation](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/advanced#kiosk_mode).

Comment: I'm running the xfce of the 12.04 (the 4.8 if not mistaken). Updating to 4.10/4.12 is dangerous ? did you use the dev team ppa in launchpad ?

Comment: @AntoineRodriguez Try it with Xfce 4.8 first; it should work with that default version. I did use the official xubuntu-dev ppas for 4.10 and 4.12, and everything installed fine, but try it with Xfce 4.8 first.