# Need to change Xubuntu(xfce) default suspend settings

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, xfce, xfce4-power-manager

If `sudo pm-suspend` works, but using the "suspend" option from the log-out menu doesn't, how can I get the log-out menu to point to just `pm-suspend` instead of whatever script it's currently using?

And:

How can I get the power manager to use just `pm-suspend` to suspend the computer after a certain length of inactivity instead of whatever script it's currently using?

I'm using Xubuntu 15.04. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/278155/how-to-change-the-hibernate-and-suspend-settings-at-a-system-wide-level-in-xfce t i think this could get you with some idea.