# Why are unexpected windows such as File Manager appearing on computer startup?

Tags: xubuntu, startup, filemanager, startup-applications

I'm using xubuntu and recently I encounter this problem:
When the computer started up, a main window Files Manager appeared automatically and I don't why this happens. There are bunch of startup applications and I can't locate which one of them causes this.

Is there any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're experiencing is XFCE's automatic session saving. It will attempt to restore the session you had before logging out.

You can nuke the cached sessions with [a quick `rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions/*`](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq#some_of_my_applications_are_always_started_when_i_login) but for long-term disablement, there is [another answer on the site that involves forcibly disabling it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250630/how-can-i-turn-off-xfce-session-saving-system-wide).

Chances are now that you know what to expect (if you leave windows open before you log out), you won't be so surprised and confused.

Comment: I feel sooo happy to learn this interesting feature in xfce now, no more confused! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Oli's answer, you can disable this feature *once* by using the following steps to shutdown instead of the normal shutdown menu entry:

1. Click the "Logout" menu entry.
2. Uncheck the "Save session for future logins" checkbox near the bottom.
3. Click the type of operation (shutdown/reboot) which you'd like to do.

---

If you want this to be unchecked by default, use the following steps:

1. Open XFCE's Setting Manager.
2. Navigate to "Session and Startup", the 'General' tab.
3. Uncheck “Automatically save session on logout”.

Reference:

1. [Some of my applications are always started when I login](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq#some_of_my_applications_are_always_started_when_i_login)

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I feel very lucky to get help from someone who know exactly what I'm experiencing.