# how to stop xubuntu from opening programs when powered on

Tags: xubuntu, apache2, shutdown, lamp, startup-applications

Whenever I shut down xubuntu, if I happen to have any programs open, they start back up when I start up xubuntu. How do I stop it from doing this? The reason I want to stop it instead of just closing all my programs before shutting down is because I have an apache server running in the background, which is stopping lampp from functioning, and the only way I know how to stop it without lampp is to shut down the computer. But then xubuntu starts it right back up when my computer starts up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the xubuntu option to save the session state. There are two possible places for this setting:

- At the bottom of the logout dialogue box there is a checkbox about saving the session state.
- At Applications-> Settings -> Xfce 4 Settings Manager -> Session and Startup

Also try removing all files in ~/.cache/sessions/

If this still fails, try modifying the kioskrc to add option "[xfce4-session] SaveSession=NONE" see: [How can I turn off Xfce session saving system-wide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250630/how-can-i-turn-off-xfce-session-saving-system-wide)

However, if your actual problem is how to shutdown Apache, then also see this official page on [how to stop Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html)

Comment: Both of those check boxes are not checked and it still does it.

Comment: Try to remove all files in ~/.cache/sessions/  or if that still fails, try modifying the kioskrc to add option "[xfce4-session] SaveSession=NONE" see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/250630/how-can-i-turn-off-xfce-session-saving-system-wide

Comment: The kioskrc thing is what finally worked for me. Thank you.